# HTML 5 - number regular expression

Tags: html

I have got an input field called Fleet no.

I want to validate it using HTML 5 to only allow the input of digits to 5 digit max length.

I have managed to only input digits but it only accepts 1 digit.

I can't put more than 1 digit. This is what i tried to do:

```
<div>
  <label for="element_1">Fleet Number </label>
  <input id="element_1" name="element_1" type="text" maxlength="255" 
  value="" required placeholder="Enter Digits only" pattern = "[0-9]"
  title='Fleet No. must contain digits only'/> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `[0-9]{1,5}`

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{1,5}" />
```

`{1,5}` means repeat the previous part 1, 2, 3, ..., 5 times.

Comment: it doesn't work, it allows letters (I just ran the snippet)

Answer (score 14):

This is the cleanest way

```html
<input type="text" pattern="\d{1,5}" title="Only digits" />
```

Comment: the `*` means zero or more times, which doesn't follow the 2 required rules which are said in the question: at least 1 and less than 6

Comment: it doesn't work, it allows letters (I just ran the snippet)

Answer (score 3):

Just add the below oninput expression into your HTML tag.
This will allow accepting the only numbers between 0 to 9.

This one also restricts accepting +, -, .(dot).

```
<input type="text" id="salary" name="salary" maxlength="3" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" />
```

'OR'

```
<input type="text" id="salary" name="salary" maxlength="3" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" />
```

I found this in one of the js fiddles, and It works for me.

Comment: I ran `run code snippet` below and they didnt work. This answer is the only correct one .

Answer (score 1):

why not for eg: using `min` and `max` arguments for `number` input:

```
<input type="number" name="element_1" min="0" max="99999">
```

This is only valid when the number is smaller than `99999` and this means it is less or equal to 5 digits.

Comment: no, because "type number" allows dashes (-) and letter "e", and he only want numbers.

Answer (score 0):

only 5 digit numeric:

See:
https://regex101.com/r/pTSwFN/1/

```
 pattern="[0-9]{5}"
```

Answer (score 0):

`pattern` attribute only work after submit (button/enter), and you may need `required="required"` to check if the input is empty.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text"
    pattern="\d{1,5}"
    required="required" 
    placeholder="enter or submit to verify" />
  <button type="">submit</button>
</form>
```

for realtime check use `HTMLFormElement.reportValidity()`

```js
function check(input) {
   if (!/^\d{1,5}$/.test(input.value)) {
     input.reportValidity()
   } 
 }
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="\d{1,5}"
    required="required" 
    oninput="check(this)"/>
  <button type="">submit</button>
</form>
```