# How to show masked character (like asterisk '*') in input type number as numbers are typed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a html input type='number' field to set PIN no (no characters are allowed) but I want the characters to be masked as I type.

I am new in web development. Please help me out.

Comment: <input type="password">

Comment: <input type="password"> takes both number and alphabet but I want only numbers

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883549/html-5-number-regular-expression

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295843/allow-only-numbers-to-be-typed-in-a-textbox. You can use password field with key press restrictions to allow numeric values

Comment: I think the reason OP wants to use type="number" because it opens up the number keypad on mobile devices. Useful on PIN inputs.

Comment: thanks  balakrishnan, but characters are not masked which is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with jQuery

```js
$(function () {

  $('#pincode').bind('keyup paste', function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  });

  $('#pincode').keyup(function () {
    var text = $(this).val().trim();
    $('#errorname').text(text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" id="sign_in_form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" style="font-weight: bold; cursor: text;"><span style="color:red;">* </span>Enter PIN</label>
    <input type="password" name="pincode" id="pincode" maxlength="6" inputmode="numeric">
  </div>
  <div id="errorname"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use like this-

```
<input type="password" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
```

[see details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19130030/3926727)

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password#Setting_length_requirements

I think this helps if you want to make input type='password' accept only numbers